# Does it make sense to compare complex numbers in certain circumstances?

Tags: complex-numbers

I know that $\mathbb{C}$ is an unordered field and that (strictly non-real) complex numbers cannot be 'compared' in the sense that one is less than/greater than another.

However, we can compare real numbers; geometrically, this is because they lie on a straight line through the origin, $0+0i$, and one real is greater than another if it's 'further' along the real line than the other.

I'm wondering whether, given that two (or more) strictly complex (i.e. ones with nonzero real and imaginary parts) numbers can be compared given that they lie on a straight line through the origin.
e.g. to me, it makes sense to say that $1+i<2+2i$, for instance, and that $i<10i,$  as one is a real multiple of the other.

Essentially, what I'm asking, is: can we compare complex numbers in any way other than comparing their moduli?

Thanks

Comment: The partial ordering you described is exactly the same as the partial ordering given by the modulus.

Comment: Yes, this can be done. The definition you're looking for is:$z \leq w$ iff there exists $r \in [1,\infty)$ such that $rz=w$. This is a genuine partial order, and it is compatible with the multiplicative structure of $\mathbb{C}$ but not the additive structure. Contrary to oxeimon's comment, this is **not** the partial order induced on $\mathbb{C}$ by the modulus function, since that is a mere preorder; more precisely, its not antisymmetric.

Comment: There is another interesting partial ordering of $\mathbb{C}$ given as follows: $z \leq w$ iff there exists $r \in [0,\infty)$ such that $z+r=w$. This is compatible with the additive structure of $\mathbb{C}$, and slightly compatible with the multiplicative. I leave it to you to work out the details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can put a [lexicographical ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) on the complex numbers, which makes it a totally ordered set. However, we cannot introduce a totally ordered relation on the complex numbers (as a field such that the field operations are compatible with the defined order) since, [every ordered field is a formally real field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field#Which_fields_can_be_ordered.3F).

Comment: What if we're comparing $a+bi$ and $c+di$, but $a<c$ and $b>d$? In this case, which is the bigger of the two?

Comment: in this case the second one is "bigger"

Comment: Oh, so it's like comparing 'Alan Smith' and 'Joe Bloggs' in their position in the phone book?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly looks like ordering words in a dictionary.

Comment: Exactly, this is why it is called "lexicographical", it is the same order as in a the dictionnary. By the whay, it is actually a total order on $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: @YannHamdaoui , No it is not a a total order, and we cannot define any totally order relation on $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Yes it is. What you cannot define is a total order relation that is operation-compatible, which is not the case of the lexicographical order. Look at the wikipedia link you gave, they state explicitely that if the order used in the construction is total (corresponds to the usual order on $\mathbb{R}$ here, which is total), so is the lexicographical order. Actually, with axiom of choice, you can build a strict total order on a arbitrary set. But once again, in $\mathbb{C}$, it won't be operation compatible. If you're not convinced, please give me two non comparable elements ?

Comment: @YannHamdaoui I think I miss understood your point, sorry. Now I think you mean complex numbers as a set can be totally ordered not as a field, and I have made that clear in my answer (I edited it). Thank you :).

Comment: Well, ordering "as a field" is just ordering the set with an order that is compatible with operations. If you talk about ordered field, then it makes no sense to say that lexicographical order is partial, because $\mathbb{C}$ with this order is NOT even an ordered field. So we obviously talk about ordering the set of complex numbers, and you even wrote "which makes it a partial ordered set". Once again, this is false, because lexicographical order is total on the set of complex numbers. And it doesn't contradict the second link precisely because it is not seen as an ordered field, but set

Comment: @YannHamdaoui I agree with you, I should have said totally ordered set, but saying that makes the set partially ordered is not wrong.

Comment: Yes you're right, but it was misleading ^^ it's just that accepted answer can be red by other people than the OP and should be precise. Thanks for edit

Comment: @YannHamdaoui Thank you, your comments made the answer better :)

Comment: @YannHamdaoui: a detail: with the Axiom of Choice, you obtain a well-order on any set. For example, it is easy to construct a total order $\mathbb C$ (cf math137's answer) but, as far as I know, the AC is necessary to a well-order.

Comment: @Taladris indeed, actually I just wanted to highlight the difference between being ordered as a field (that can be only $\mathbb{R}$ itself if it contains it) and as a set, by saying that with AC you can even totally order an arbitrary set, so the "well-ordering" part was not even relevant here, but since it's given for free by the well-ordering theorem...

Comment: -1 this answer is irrelevant to the question, which is obviously a question about useful partial orderings of the complex. This should have been a comment, or at best a remark in a larger and more relevant answer. **Edit.** Also, your answer is full of typos. For instance, in the first sentence you explain how to totally-order $\mathbb{C}$, whereas in the second sentence, you claim that totally-ordering $\mathbb{C}$ is impossible.

Comment: @goblin OP asks "Essentially, what I'm asking, is: can we compare complex numbers in any way other than comparing their moduli?"

Comment: @Math137, but read between the lines. What they really want to know is: can we **usefully** compare complex numbers in any other way than comparing their moduli? Of course, every set can be well-ordered, so without the usefulness condition, the question is completely vacuous.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it totally makes sense.

In order to use $\gt$, $\lt$ and $=$ the same way they are used on real numbers, a many-to-one relation that maps complex numbers into real numbers will suffice.

More generally, an order is nothing but a relation. A total order is a relation $R$ that is transitive, asymmetrical and connected.

> Transitive: if $xRy$ and $yRz$ then $xRz$, e.g. if 3>2 and 2>1 then 3>1;
>
> Asymmetrical: if $xRy$ then $yRx$ must be false, e.g. if 3 > 1 then 1 > 3 must be false;
>
> Connected: Given any two terms $x$ and $y$, either $xRy$ or $yRx$.
>
> Source: Russell, Bertrand. [Introduction to Mathematical Philosophy](http://people.umass.edu/%7Eklement/imp/imp-ebk.pdf), "Chapter IV The Definition of Order"

**Example1: Who gets off the Ferris Wheel first**

Given any two complex numbers $a=r_1e^{i\phi}$ and $b=r_2e^{i\psi}$,

we define $a>b$ as

> $(\phi > \psi) $ or $(\phi=\psi$ and $r_1>r_2 )$

This means that the person who has travelled a greater degree from the starting point or, if the travelled degrees are the same, the person who is on the further end of the spoke gets off first.

> Thus, $3e^{i\pi}> 2e^{i\pi}> 3e^{i\dfrac{\pi}{2}}$

**Example2: Sailing in crosswinds**
[image]

Suppose you are sailing towards Northeast$(\dfrac{π}{4})$. You can produce various lifts by adjusting your sail, but some lifts are better than others because they produce more forward thrusts. Given a lift $fe^{i\theta}$, the forward thrust it produces is $fcos(θ−\dfrac{π}{4})$. This is the value you use to compare various lifts.

**Edit:** Depending on the field of terms, this comparison does not necessarily give rise to a total order. Different lifts can produce the same forward thrusts, thus the asymmetrical requirement is violated. Nevertheless, you can still compare lifts.

If you know Ruby programming language, you can customize the spaceship operator to sort complex numbers.

Comment: But, according to this approach, which term dominates out of the distance travelled, $r$, and the angle from the starting point, $\theta$? Say $r_1>r_2$ but $\theta_1<\theta_2$. In this case, which is bigger? Is there a way to get a weighted average of $\theta$ and $r$, in general?

Comment: The angle dominates. In your example, $r_2\angle\theta_2$ is greater.

Comment: This is a very practical question, by the way. Imagine a ship detects a salvo of anti-ship missiles from all directions, the computerized phalanx would have to quickly decide which missile to shoot first.

Comment: Do you have a formula to calculate the weighted average of $r$ and $\theta$? Or is it always the case that the angle dominates, even if $\theta_1$ is only slightly bigger than $\theta_2$, but $r_1<<r_2$?

Comment: In this particular example yes, $\theta$ always dominates. Just imagine the order people get off a Ferris Wheel.

Comment: The point is, in order to create a series(with comparable properties),all you need is to construct a relation that is transitive, asymmetrical and connected.

Comment: Oh, so you've defined $re^{i\theta}<se^{i \phi}$ iff $\theta>\phi$?

Comment: Is that just as arbitrary as choosing $r$ to dominate or is there a reason for this?

Comment: In the anti-missile example, the "precedes" relation would be like this $a$ precedes $b$ if $r_1 < r_2$ or $r_1=r_2 and \theta_1 < \theta_2$.

Comment: Yes, it's an arbitrary example that satisfies the three relational requirements.

Comment: Going back to your missile analogy, surely it would be unwise to first shoot down a missile 10 miles away that requires a rotation of 10 degrees, than a missile 0.2 miles away but requires a rotation of 180 degrees?

Comment: The weighted algorithm is a good question. I believe there is one, but I can't come up with it this moment.

Comment: You understand me perfectly.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Again, the key point is the three relational requirements.

Comment: No, I mean what do you mean by 'you understand me perfectly'?

Comment: You totally understand my missile analogy.

Comment: Ahh- I thought it was some romantic phrase that suggests we are destined for each other.

Comment: The core idea is, in order to create a series, all you need is to construct a relation that is **transitive, connected, asymetrical**

Comment: I added another example.