# Extending the set of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, real-numbers

Mathematics as a science became richer when Cantor invented the real numbers. Then scientists wanted to solve equations which were not solvable in the real numbers so they invented the complex numbers. My question is, will we ever need to extend the complex numbers to some other set which will contain all other existing sets and help us for something? Are complex numbers extendable? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Complex numbers were discovered before Cantor came around...Real numbers were already known way before Cantor. However if you want to credit Cantor, read about set theory for example

Comment: There's the [quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion), [polynomial rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring#The_polynomial_ring_K.5BX.5D), function fields, other algebras over the complex numbers...

Comment: In most formulations of set theory, there isn't a "set that contains all other existing sets", by the way. This is the content of [Russell's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_set#Russell.27s_paradox).

Comment: @imranfat: While the OP is grossly incorrect by saying that Cantor invented the real numbers, he did give the familiar Cauchy sequences definition of them (at the same time Dedekind gave his definition).

Comment: @AsafKaragila I readily admit you are right about that. That extention didn't cross my mind when I wrote down my comment, and I wonder if the OP knew about that. I also made my comment about Cantor's contribution of the set theory as I did not want to discredit a mathematician who contributed more than I would probably ever do :)

Comment: Just for the fun of it, we could add the hyperreals to the discussion...

Comment: Related: [Hamilton's three dimensional algebra](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/563065/); [Why are the only division algebras over the real numbers the real numbers, the complex numbers, and the quaternions?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529/); [Why is quaternion algebra 4d and not 3d?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72012/); [Is there such thing as an imaginary (imaginary number)?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789932/); [Is there a third dimension of numbers?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32100/)

Comment: @Brad I'm told that naturals, integers, rationals and irrationals are subsets of the real numbers. You say this isn't true?

Comment: No, that's certainly true. You were asking about a set that contains *all other existing sets*, not just those ones.

Comment: @Brad For me all other existing sets were the ones i just mentioned. Could you please give an example?

Comment: The set $\mathbb R^2$ of ordered pairs of real numbers isn't a subset of $\mathbb R$, for example. Neither is the power set of $\mathbb R$, which is the set whose elements are the subsets of $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To solve polynomials, the answer is **no**. The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra says that every (non-constant) polynomial, of degree $n$, with complex coefficients has $n$ roots (including repeated roots) in $\mathbb{C}$.

As a result of this, the set of complex numbers, unlike the set of real numbers, is algebraically closed, which means that we cannot 'escape' $\mathbb{C}$ using any elementary operations, like $+, - , \times, \div, \sqrt{}, e^{...}$ etc. So, in this sense, we don't really 'need' to extend the complex numbers.

However, there do exist hypercomplex numbers, like the quaternions, $\mathbb{H}$, which, instead of using just one imaginary unit $i$, use three: $i, j, k$, each satisfying:$$i^2=j^2=k^2=ijk=-1$$

Quaternions are used in modelling 3D vectors, and have a lot of use in 3D mechanics.
A useful property of a quaternion is that it does **not** satisfy commutativity: e.g. $i\times j \neq j \times i$.

N0w, if you **still** want to go further, you can explore the octonions, $\mathbb{O},$ which are an extension of the quaternions.
Octonions have 7 imaginary units: $e_1, e_2, ...e_7$.

Octonions have far fewer (that I know of, at least) practical uses that quaternions.
Octonions also have the interesting property that they lack associativity: e.g. $x\times(y\times z) \neq (x \times y) \times z$ (for $x,y,z \in \mathbb{O}$).

And, finally, at least as far as mathematical interest has gone, we have the sedenions, $\mathbb{S}$.
These are an extension of the octonions and have 15 imaginary units: $e_1,e_2,e_3,...,e_{15}$. The special property about the sedenions is that they have zero-divisors (meaning that there exist non-zero sedenions $x$ and $y$ such that $xy=0$). Interesting, this property, isn't it? Not particularly, intuitive, to say the least.

Now, I'll leave as an exercise for you to find out about the **applications** of hypercomplex numbers, and how to multiply them (hint: Google 'Fano plane mnemonic', which explains how to multiply octonions- this same idea can be extended to the sedenions).

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomplex_number

Comment: Also, you 'can' extend even these (hypercomplex) number systems to ones with an arbitrary number of elements (see this- http://www.tony5m17h.net/Voudons.html   which talks about so-coined 'voudons', $\mathbb{V}$, 'chingons', $\mathbb{X}$, routons, $\mathbb{U}$, voudons, $\mathbb{V}$, etc.), but whether or not these have any practical uses is a different story.

Also, bear in mind that, as you'extend' a number system, you lose algebraic properties the higher up the hypercomplex ladder (e.g. commutativity, associativity, etc.), so a hypercomplex number system, with, say, $2^{20}$ elements,...

Comment: ...will probably not have the algebraic properties to be considered even remotely useful.

Comment: There exist a hierarchy for these number systems? I mean if is possibile to order of all these systems, the equations they allow us to solve and algebraic properties that lose validity?

Comment: @MphLee I'm not sure what you're asking, but if it's along the lines of 'why do *equations* lose their validity higher up the hypercomplex hierachy', then that's not true- what I'm saying is, as you go further up the ladder, you lose essential properties like associativity, and going from $\mathbb{O}$ to $\mathbb{S}$, you no longer have a division algebra, so, if you go even further up, you're likely to lose so many properties (e.g. power-associaitvity) that the algebra that you're left with won't be very *practical*, due to its strange algebraic properties.

Comment: @MphLee Also, I use the terms 'ladder' 'hierarchy' in a loose sense, when I'm actually referring to the dimension of the algebra. They are 'ordered' (in terms of their 'size') as follows:
$\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C} \subset \mathbb{H} \subset \mathbb{O} \subset \mathbb{S} \subset \mathbb{P} \subset \mathbb{X} \subset \mathbb{U} \subset \mathbb{V}$. In this case, each 'successor' algebra has twice the dimension of the previous one.
Also note that there may be *more* (possibly infinitely many more) solutions to equations, if we extend from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{H}$, and so on.

Comment: Yea you got the question. About  equations that lose their validity im talking about associativity equation and the others properties: if there is a way to predict wich usefull algebraic property we are going to lose in the 'successor' algebra. In this way we could make an ordered hierarchy of properties that fail to be satisfied by the systems while the dimension grows. Also... math is math and i like it...nothing to do with "cyberlife"

Comment: There is no reason to restrict to non-constant polynomials. A non-zero constant polynomial has degree $n=0$ and $n=0$ complex solutions, so the statement is just as true for those. Only for the zero polynomial you need an exception.

Comment: @alexqwx I'm asking myself what property did we lose with complex numbers? The property of being an ordered set isn't related to multiplication algebra. Any ideas? This is probably a "soft" question...

Comment: @orion Not at all a soft question! Going from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$, apart from *total* linear ordering, we lose equality of the complex conjugate. i.e. $x+yi \neq x-yi$, whereas, in $\mathbb{R}, x(+0i)=x(-0i)$.

Also, note the emphasis of *total* linear ordering; there are ways to compare complex numbers; e.g. comparing their moduli or lexicographic ordering- see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786908/does-it-make-sense-to-compare-complex-numbers-in-certain-circumstances/787162?noredirect=1#comment1632652_787162

Answer (score 13):

As an account of history, the question is nonsense.  Real numbers and complex numbers were thought about before Cantor's birth (he was born in the 19th century), and solving algebraic equations with no real solutions was not the motive for complex numbers.

Complex numbers were introduced in the 16th century in order to find **real** solutions of third-degree algebraic equations with real coefficients.

That sort of process for solving algebraic equations will not take you beyond the complex numbers, because a theorem, often misleadingly called the "fundamental theorem of algebra" says that every algebraic equation with complex coefficients has a complex solution.

But, as others have already noted here, there are other motives for extending the system of complex numbers.  The quaternions are the most widely known example.

Answer (score 6):

You can extend the complex numbers and get [quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion). Which can be used in, for example, 3D computer graphics instead of matrices. It is possible to extend the quaternions as many times as you want, like you did with the complex numbers to get the quaternions.

Answer (score 3):

Others have already mentioned the quaternions.  I just wanted to mention the [surcomplex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number#Surcomplex_numbers), which, while lacking the property of being a set, satisfy all the properties of an algebraicly closed field.  You get these numbers by taking the surreal numbers (a gigantic totally ordered field containing every totally ordered field in existence) and adjoining the element $i$, which is analagous to how you construct $\mathbb{C}$ by adjoining $i$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

Extending further is possible, but you loose certain nice properties. Quaternions are no more commutative, octonions no more associative. In higher dimensions, you cannot expect to have any kind of "reasonably nice multiplication" and "norm", because higher dimensional spheres are not fully paralelizable. It means, you cannot choose a basis of the tangent space of $1$ in the sphere $S^{n-1}$ of unit vectors and extend it to $n-1$ independent nonzero vector fields by left multiplication. (except from $n=1,2,4,8$; this is known from algebraic topology).

On the other hand, there are some nice structures in dimensions $2^n$, such as Clifford algebras, or the [Cayley-Dickson construcion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction#Further_algebras).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really want to know is the fact that there is no (strict) extension of $\mathbb C$ which is a field. (In fact, I think you can even say that the only field extensions of $\mathbb R$ are $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$.)

**Edit:** For the record, the answer above is wrong as it stands (see comment by Asaf Karagila below). It should have said that there are no *finite* (meaning finite-dimensional) field extensions of $\mathbb C$. The same modification applies to the parenthetical remark in the original answer.

Comment: That's plain false. There are no **algebraic** extensions, though.

Comment: Yes, you're right of course. I guess I should modify my answer. I really had in mind finite field extensions but was trying to use simple language.